# Custom shader - Unity - Diffuse+Lightmap+normal+cubemap

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, shader

I've been working on a custom shader for a project using Unity 4.6 because Unity's shaders offers a great variety of options but not the one i'm looking for. 
I've looked on Stackoverflow about my shader's issue, but every question is about tricky and higly technical issue using shader. I think mine is quite simple (for an experienced developper) but haven't been posted yet.

Here is the problem :
I want to merge 2 shaders to get a "Diffuse+normal+cubemap+lighmap" shader.

**So, on one side I have a "Diffuse + NormalMap + LightMap" shaders which looks like this (it's the legacy/lighmap bumpedspec a with a little tweaking to get the specular shinyness):**

```
 Shader "Legacy Shaders/Lightmapped/Custom/BumpedSpec" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _SpecColor ("Specular Color", Color) = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
    _Shininess ("Shininess", Range (0.03, 1)) = 0.078125
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _BumpMap ("Normalmap", 2D) = "bump" {}
    _LightMap ("Lightmap (RGB)", 2D) = "black" {}
}

SubShader {
    LOD 200
    Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf BlinnPhong
struct Input {
  float2 uv_MainTex;
  float2 uv_BumpMap;
  float2 uv2_LightMap;
};
sampler2D _MainTex;
sampler2D _LightMap;
sampler2D _BumpMap;
float4 _Color;
float _Shininess;

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
{
  half4 tex = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
  o.Albedo = tex.rgb * _Color;
  half4 lm = tex2D (_LightMap, IN.uv2_LightMap);
  o.Emission = lm.rgb*o.Albedo.rgb;
  o.Gloss = tex.a;
  o.Alpha = lm.a * _Color.a;
  o.Specular = _Shininess;
  o.Normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_BumpMap, IN.uv_BumpMap));
}
ENDCG
}
FallBack "Legacy Shaders/Lightmapped/VertexLit"
}
```

**And on the other side, i've got a shader with "Diffuse+cubemap+Lightmap" which looks like this :**

```
Shader "Custom/CubeLightmap" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _ReflectColor ("Reflection Color", Color) = (1,1,1,0.5)
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB) RefStrength (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Cube ("Reflection Cubemap", Cube) = "_Skybox" { TexGen CubeReflect }
    _LightMap ("Lightmap (RGB)", 2D) = "lightmap" { LightmapMode }
}
SubShader {
    LOD 200
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }

CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Lambert
sampler2D _MainTex;
samplerCUBE _Cube;
sampler2D _LightMap;
fixed4 _Color;
fixed4 _ReflectColor;
struct Input {
    float2 uv_MainTex;
    float3 worldRefl;
    float2 uv2_LightMap;
};
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    fixed4 tex = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
    fixed4 c = tex * _Color;
    o.Albedo = c.rgb;   
    half4 lm = tex2D(_LightMap,IN.uv2_LightMap);   
    fixed4 reflcol = texCUBE (_Cube, IN.worldRefl);
    reflcol *= tex.a;
    o.Emission = lm.rgb * reflcol.rgb * _ReflectColor.rgb;
    o.Alpha = reflcol.a * _ReflectColor.a * lm.a;
}
ENDCG
}   
FallBack "Reflective/VertexLit"
}
```

So I want to merge both off them (a.k.a include cubemap in the first one or include normalmap in the second one) and I can't figure it out for the moment.

So I'm in need of some advice or help to achieve it.

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: *Experienced developer* says nothing, are you experienced in shader writing? Or more of a beginner in shaders, and for what purpose do you want this shader. There might be simpler shaders that reach the same effect.

Comment: I am new in shader's customisation but I'm used to Unity3D and scripting.
The goal of this shader is to add lots of effects for a realistic rendering.

I use the lightmap from a Vray render and i need the normal map and the cube reflection within the same shader to get the material to behave correctly in real time. Finally i use the diffuse to get a standard texture that I can switch to get various visuals.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are looking to create a radiosity normal mapping shader. This will require you to at least know the basics of C++, and HSLS[image]

The biggest problem you will encounter will be how to compute radiosity normal maps, as this requires a specially crafted light mapper. The only software I know of that does this is [Beast by AutoDesk](http://gameware.autodesk.com/beast/features)

After that you will need some simple shaders. There is some well documented explanations, and relevant code located at

- [Half Life 2 shading](http://www2.ati.com/developer/gdc/D3DTutorial10_Half-Life2_Shading.pdf)
- [Valve Software](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_EfficientSelfShadowedRadiosityNormalMapping.pdf)

Comment: Many thanks for thoses informations. It look like a bit more difficult than merging the 2 unity's shaders of my first message >.<
I'll look into it more closely and post my result

Comment: it *is* more difficult then just merging 2 shaders Hope you will be succesfull. Good luck